# Eliminar uno de los sistemas linux de mi pc

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Tengo tres sistemas operativos en mi pc:

-Windows 10

-Ubuntu 18.04

-linux Lite

Lo que quiero es eliminar Ubuntu 18.04 de mi PC pero el grub que me da la opcion de escoger el sistemar operativo a arrancar es de ubuntu.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Como puedo eliminar ubuntu sin afectar el dual boot de Windows y Linux Lite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primero, tienes que arrancar el Linux Lite y instalar un grub desde ello. Una vez estés en el Linux Lite, abre un terminal y ejecuta:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Esto va a instalar el grub en el MBR (master boot record) del primer disco de tu sistema. Una vez hecho, puedes reiniciar y averiguar que ahora tu grub es lo del Linux Lite. Y, si todo ha ido bien, puedes simplemente borrar las particiones de tu Ubuntu.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, al poner el ultimo comando me dio como resultado esto:                                                                                       Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: Al reiniciar no se abre el grub de linux lite, sigue con el de ubuntu